# Wifi Direct and internet simultaneously?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-direct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect to a wifi ap and 3g network simultaneously?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wifi-ap-and-3g-network-simultaneously)

Is it possible to use Wifi Direct and regular internet at the same time?

For example, could an app be written that connects to the router's Wifi AP as a Wifi Direct peer? Would this app need root?

If this is possible, please link to any code samples or existing apps or documentation that would be a helpful starting point. Thanks!

Comment: Code samples? Sorry, wrong site. Development questions are expressly off-topic here. ([FAQ]) However, asking for code samples at [so] will get this question closed as well.