# Can't reach internet via wifi when wifi-direct printer is connected

Tags: wi-fi, printing, wifi-direct

Maybe I didn't understand at all the concept of wifi-direct, but, **can an android be connected in the same time to a wifi for internet and a printer via wifidirect** ?

When i'm connected to my printer, i lose the ability to reach the internet via "normal" wifi.

This could be a duplicate of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31966/wifi-direct-and-internet-simultaneously), but it has no answer and is marked as duplicate of [that question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wifi-ap-and-3g-network-simultaneously), which does **not** cover that subject (we're talking about **2 wifis**, not 3G + wifidirect).

Comment: You only have one WiFi chip so you can only either connect to a hotspot or host one, not both at the same time. (WiFi direct uses a hosted hotspot for connection so your phone acts like one) With two individual WiFi adapters it would be possible to do.

Comment: Thx GiantTree ; so if I want my app to be able to print, i have to programmatically switch connexion in-app ?

(could you put your comment in an answer so i up it ?)

Answer (score 6):

According to SO this should be possible:

- [Can WIFI direct and WIFI station work simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15540884/2533433) says it should work if the driver supports *multi-role*.
- Explicit for Android: [Android running Wifi Lan and Wifi Direct simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25253836/2533433) describes *Simultaneous wifi direct and network wifi is an optional feature for devices. Some devices allow this and some do not,* with a pointer to the last item on [this FAQ](http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct).

That "last item" no longer is the last item, though – so let me quote that "official reply":<sup>1</sup>

> All devices certified under the Wi-Fi Direct program allow the user to connect to an infrastructure or a Wi-Fi Direct-certified network. Some devices certified under the Wi-Fi Direct program support connections to both an infrastructure network and Wi-Fi Direct-certified group at the same time (e.g. a laptop may support an infrastructure connection while also belonging to a Wi-Fi Direct-certified group). Simultaneous connection to a Wi-Fi Direct-certified group and an infrastructure network is an optional feature.

---

<sup>**1:** That site belongs to the *Wi-Fi Alliance®*, see [Who we are](http://www.wi-fi.org/who-we-are)</sup>

Comment: standard or not, should work or not: It will work in most devices simultaneously, but not in all. Implementation of Wifi-Direct differs from device to device, there are even major differences between devices from the same manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

You only have one WiFi adapter so you only can either connect to a hotspot or host one, not do both at the same time. This is so because WiFi-direct is basically acting as a hotspot for others.

With two individual WiFi adapters it would be possible because you would have two individual network connections.

Answer (score -1):

Wifi can be used for single operation only. You can use either wifi or hotspot.