# Route Application through Mobile Data when on Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, proxy, whatsapp-messenger, mobile-data

While on Wifi, [Whatsapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp) won't work on my Galaxy Note 2 due to my work proxy. I have found no proxying application that will work, yet. (My work is using an HTTP Proxy).

Is there an application that will route certain phone apps (such as Whatsapp) through mobile data, while still allowing other apps to use Wifi access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, as soon as WiFi gets connected, the mobile network shuts down -- so you cannot use both simultaneously. Which means: no, even a proxy allowing for exceptions would not do, as the other network simply is no longer available.

Quoting from [CyanogenMod Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=4322):

> Each time you activate WiFi you'll lose 3g connection. That's normal behaviour of Android network manager.

There were attempts on "hacking" that, as you can e.g. find [here](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/let-wifi-and-3g-connection-work-together-by-hacking-connectivityservice-java/). This source from the Stanford university also makes clear on the standard behaviour:

> - Given WiFI is connected, then turn on  3G data connection. 3G connection will be automatically torn down by Connectivity Service.
> - Given 3G is connected, then turn on WiFi connection. Connectivity Service will tear down the existing 3G connection.

Except from "hacking attempts" as described by the Stanford example, I know of no solution to the issue.

Comment: I don't understand why you gave an answer that it *is* possible in September 2012, yet now in December 2012, claim that it's *not* possible.  Could you care to explain your conflicting answers?  http://android.stackexchange.com/a/29791/26023

Comment: Good find. Have you tried the other solution? I never got any feedback on that, except for what Matt wrote over there: *It didn't work.* Also note what I've quoted here is "general behaviour" (not taking that app into account). Still, it's a good pointer; I'd love to get more feedback on that app – if possible, even positive feedback :)

Comment: Well, you're the one who gave me the links to both of these answers in my question, I'm simply linking together the two unlinked links you gave me. :-)

Comment: @avesus found some nice link in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5883882/84661

Comment: @cnst Yes, I remember we've discussed that (in chat?) a while ago. But AFAIR that's something each app must so itself, so you cannot set a "global switch" from the outside. I might remember wrongly, though...