# Is there a way for 3G to not disconnect when connecting to WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, mobile-data, sip

WiFi is unreliable, I wouldn't trust WiFi for SIP calls, I've disabled WiFi within CSipSimple.

Now every time I connect to WiFi, my SIP registration seems to go away, and I'm not receiving any calls at all.  It's also unclear what happens when you do receive a call, unlock the phone to pick it up, and then the phone connects to WiFi (which it presumably didn't do during the sleep in order to conserve the power).

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: At least related, and maybe helpful: [How do I connect to a wifi ap and 3g network simultaneously?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29769/16575) / [Route Application through Mobile Data when on Wifi](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35829/16575)

Comment: Since @avesus answer and the corresponding discussion went away somehow, here's the useful link he has brought to my attention: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5883882/84661

Comment: That's a way for developers to do it, so it wouldn't fit as an answer here (though it shows that it's possible). So your solution would be asking the CSipSimple guys to implement that – or asking at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) whether there's an Android app that could do this. Though I assume for doing that *for other apps* would require root access. (As for what THIS site is: not for development questions, but for *end users* – see our [help/on-topic] and our [tour]).