# How can I keep my mobile data connection up when establishing a non-internet capable WiFi connection?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network, 5.1-lollipop

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to stream music wirelessly inside my car. The Pi has a wireless network without real a exit to the outside world. I want to connect to that 'internet-less' network and still be able to stream music with my mobile LTE connection. The PI works perfectly with iPhones. I set a static IP on the iPhone without specifying DNS and works as intended. I can't achieve that with my Nexus 5 (Android 5.1). As soon as I connect to the Pi network, the LTE network is gone so I cant stream Pandora, GMusic, nothing.

How can I achieve this in Android 5.1? Is it possible?

Comment: Related: [How do I connect to a wifi ap and 3g network simultaneously?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29769/16575) / [Route Application through Mobile Data when on Wifi](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35829/16575). Note the two *seem* to contradict: the second one describes the *general* rules, while the first gives a possible solution nobody here confirmed yet.